# Solenoid doesn't actuate when driven through MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, solenoid

I'm trying to drive a solenoid with a GPIO on a Raspberry Pi.  Here's the schematic:

[image]

The current through the solenoid and MOSFET should be:

[image]

So the voltage drop across the MOSFET should be:

[image]

leaving us with `13.8V` across the solenoid, which should be enough to actuate the `12V` solenoid.

Naturally I've tried actuating it directly:

[image]

This works just fine.

Suspecting that maybe the MOSFET wasn't fully switched on, I took the Raspi out of the mix and tried applying `4V` directly to the gate:

[image]

but it doesn't actuate...

I've also tried replacing the solenoid/diode with a simple LED/resistor combo and it lights up as expected in both the Raspi/non-Raspi configurations, so the MOSFET appears to be switching as expected...

What am I missing here??  Why won't the solenoid actuate when I have the MOSFET in the mix?

---

Parts:

- [IRF510 MOSFET](http://www.kitsandparts.com/IRF510.pdf) (from Radioshack)
- [1N4148 Diode](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/179215.pdf)
- [DC 12V Solenoid](http://amzn.com/B00B300KQK) (amazon)

---

### Solution

As pointed out by Respawned Fluff and The Photon, I was fundamentally confused about some of the parameters of my MOSFET.  Specifically, \$V_{gs(threshold)}\$ is *not* the point at which \$R_{ds}\$ becomes \$R_{ds(on)}\$.  \$V_{gs(threshold)}\$ on this MOSFET is 2-4V, so I thought I could switch it on with 3.3V.  However, the value I needed to switch this guy on is actually 10V (read from the \$R_{ds(on)}\$ row on the datasheet).

Per Respawned Fluff's suggestion, I added a MOSFET driver between my logic output and the MOSFET and, sure enough, things started working perfectly.  I probably also could have swapped out my MOSFET for a logic-level one.  Here's the final working circuit:

[image]

The MOSFET driver is [MIC4452YN](http://amzn.com/B00DK2C7YM).

Comment: You should apply higher voltages to your Vgs. In a thumb-rule you have to apply 0.5 VCC for better action in saturation regime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the datasheet of your MOSFET does try to spoonfeed you how to use it properly (as a switch):

[image]

You need 10V Vgs to get that Rds(on). You're giving it 4V Vgs and expecting the same Rds(on)? Alas it doesn't work that way. It seems to me you've used the Vgs(th) value in your design, but that only guarantees you 250uA on the drain:

[image]

That actually translates (in the datasheet test conditions with Vds=Vgs) to 4V/250uA=16Kohm Rdson at threshold. So most of the voltage drop would be on the MOSFET and almost nothing on the solenoid's coil if that's the Rdson you're actually getting. (Put your solenoid in series with a 10K or 15K resistor, straight to the source sans MOSFET and see if it still turns on. I bet it won't.) Of course this Rdson a worst case scenario since that Vgsth is the max [=worst case] value. More on how to navigate a MOSFET datasheet is found in [my previous answer to a very similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/195080/54580). Expecting awesome Rds(on) at Vgs(th) is a perennial newbie gotcha, it seems.

Your Amazon solenoid doesn't have anything resembling a datasheet, but you can measure the voltage drop across the solenoid's coil and/or the current through it to see exactly what's going on.

A respectable solenoid datasheet has data that lets you know exactly how much voltage you need to turn it on (and how much current it draws at that point). [For example, this series](https://www.samson.de/pdf_en/t37010en.pdf):

[image]

If were using their "12V" (nominal) solenoid, at least 9.6V are needed to turn it on and it will pull at least 1.52mA at this point. (It also gives you the turn-off voltage.) Since you don't have such data available for your solenoid, you'll have to determine it experimentally (e.g. using it directly with a variable voltage source) and then decide what you need to switch it on.

Comment: Dang I had read \$V_{gs(th)}\$ MAX=4v as "don't put more than 4v here or you'll fry your chip". I confirmed that applying 15v at the gate does cause the solenoid to actuate, so now I just need to figure out how to switch that from my pi. I've tried some things with a BJT I had sitting around but to no avail.  Apparently I need to review my microelectronics notes from school, too much time in software it seems... :) Thanks for the detailed answer and I'll definitely be giving your other answer a read.

Comment: Actually probably smarter for me to find a different MOSFET that fits my operating parameters better, rather than trying to shoehorn the RadioShack into my application. This [FQP30N06L](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10213) from SparkFun seems to fit the bill (somewhere north of 10A through \$I_d\$ when \$V_{gs} = 3.3V\$ and \$V_{ds} > 11V\$ )

Comment: @mgalgs: That FQP30N06L is also a standard 10V MOSFET so won't make a difference. IF you want to change the MOSFET, you'll want a 2.5V mosfet for RPi to drive comfortably, e.g. [FDN335N](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FD/FDN335N.pdf). You could also buy a MOSFET driver IC. The are a lot of them on the market. A driver like that allows you translate low-level logic voltages into the higher voltage needed for a standard (=10V Vgs) MOSFET. An example that would work here is [MCP1402](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22052b.pdf)

Comment: Actually FD335N can't handle the max current that your solenoid needs (2.15A) because it tops at 1.7A itself. Something like [FDMA430NZ](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FD/FDMA430NZ.pdf) would be fine, but will very difficult to solder correctly by hand (has power pad). Alas it's rather difficult to find high-current and low-voltage MOSFETs that don't come in tricky packages like that. A MOSFET driver is less difficult to work with in that respect.

Comment: @mgalgs: Unfortunately I can't paste here a parametric search URL for digikey because it's too long for this box, but you can get it from http://pastebin.com/1cwrkjD1. The first hit there is a [ZXMN2F34FHTA](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ZXMN2F34FH.pdf) which would work and is not the craziest thing to solder. (SOT-23)

Comment: Wait, looking at Figure 1 on the datasheet for the FQP30N06L it seems like with \$V_{gs} =3.3V\$ and \$V_{ds} = ~13V\$ I should be able to sink up to about 15A at the drain, implying an \$R_{ds(on)}\$ of about 600 \$m \Omega\$ and a voltage drop across the MOSFET in the ballpark of 1-2V. Doesn't leave much margin but it *might* work, don't you think? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: @mgal Might work indeed. I'm worried that it says "250μs Pulse Test" on that graph, so continuous Id might not be that good. The graph in figure 3 in that datasheet plots Rdson at 5V and 10V Vgs so it does look quite usable at 5V (so possibly at 3.3V as well). I'm not sure why they didn't advertise this as a feature on the first page of the datasheet though, i.e. they could have branded it as a 5V logic MOSFET at the very least. Alas, I don't have hands-on experience with that MOSFET. You might want to ask this as a separate question, since it will get more eyes that way.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that this is a MOSFET with 100V max Vds and logic MOSFETs typically don't go that high in terms Vds. So maybe they wanted to avoid the case where a potential customer saw "logic MOSFET" part and skipped it because of that.

Comment: The again [RFP12N10L](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/RF/RFP12N10L.pdf) goes to 100V Vds and is advertised [by the same manufacturer] as a logic level MOSFET... so I really don't know why they didn't think that would a good selling point for FQP30N06L. Actually, after looking at RFP12N10L's datatasheet more carefully, I think I've figured it out: that one is characterized down to 2V Vgs, so perhaps they though that only 3V (for FQP30N06L) is not good enough.

Comment: But RFP12N10L is not much better (than FQP30N06L) at 3V in terms of Id current. In fact it looks a bit worse.

Comment: Actually, the old datasheet that Sparkfun links for http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP30N06L.pdf is different than the new Fairchild one https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FQ/FQP30N06L.pdf in terms of what they advetise. The old one does advertise it as a logic level MOSFET! I guess the manufacturer changed their mind but not necessarily for technical reasons. Might some sort of sales strategy to move their other products as well.

Comment: Another oddity is that (either old or new datasheet) for FQP30N06L says on the first page that 60V is the max Vds... but then the graph shows it go up to 100V.

Comment: Huh, ok.  I'll give the FQP30N06L a shot, but I ordered a MOSFET driver today anyways, just to be safe.  Thanks a lot for all the tips.

Comment: @mgalgs: It seems I was right about the reason for rebranding see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24942030#24942030

Answer (score 1):

Note Figure 1 of the datasheet of your MOSFET:

[image]

The Rds(on) value applies to the left part of the curves, low values of \$V_{DS}\$ where \$I_D\$ depends strongly on \$V_{DS}\$. For higher values of \$V_{DS}\$, you enter the *saturation* regime and the current now depends mainly on \$V_{GS}\$ rather than \$V_{DS}\$.

For your device, in order to get to the point where it can deliver 2 A, you need to apply around 5.5 V to the gate. For a robust design you probably should apply 1 V or so above this to ensure you are operating in the linear regime rather than saturation at your operating point.

Comment: I think your last sentence is incorrect. I think you want to state that he should be operating in the saturation regime.

Comment: @MichaelKaras When they handed out terminology MOSFETs were away partying. "Saturation region" in a MOSFET is not "turned on hard" but ~~ linearish controlled region. ie NOT the same as bipolar term saturation. Highly illogical (I think) but we seem top be stuck with it.

Comment: Man my eyes usually glaze over when I see these graphs in the datasheet. And therein lies my problem :). Applying a higher voltage to the gate works, as you (and the datasheet) predicted. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelKaras, see [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#/media/File:IvsV_mosfet.svg) on Wikipedia for the names of the operating regions in MOSFETs.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I am familiar with the terms and regions. I was just blanking out and thinking in terms of a current mode BJT when I read your sentence as pointed out by Russell McMahon.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, I actually just remember "the names for MOSFETs are screwy" and go look them up when I need to write about them.